# Extract email-ids and names using perl

Tags: perl, email, extract

I'm trying to write a Perl script to parse a directory full of emails and names and extract an email address and corresponding name.

At the moment I'm parsing for the word `Email Address     :` and then extracting the line, but this is where I am stuck.

The data is in the following format:

```
Name                :John van

Email Address       :john@abc.com
```

I need to get this data into two variables like `$name` and `$email`.

Is there a better way to parse the files to get the email address and name? How do I deal with the strings and re arrange them.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: please show us a short part of the input file.. then i can help you.

Comment: i have given the extract of the file as an example in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely an easier way of doing this but try:

From Input:

```
Name:   John Van

Email Address:  john@abc.com

Name:   John Doe

Email Address:  johnD@123.com


#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $emails = 'email.txt';
open my $input, '<', $emails or die "Can't open $emails: $!";

my (%data, @name, @email);
while(<$input>){
    push @name, $1 if /Name:\s+(.*)/;
    push @email, $1 if /Email Address:\s+(.*)/;
    $data{$name[$_]} = $email[$_] for 0 .. $#name;
}

for my $name (keys %data){
    my $email = $data{$name};
    print "$name\t$email\n"
}
```

Outputs:

```
John Doe    johnD@123.com
John Van    john@abc.com
```

Comment: I need something like: $name = John van and $email = john@abc.com

Answer (score 1):

data: (the \n is only implicit for understanding)

```
Name                :John van\n
\n 
Email Address       :john@abc.com\n
\n
```

regex based:

```
use Data::Dumper;    
my @data = m/Name\s*:([A-Za-z\s]*)\n\nEmail Address\s*:([A-Za-z\s]*@[A-Za-z\s]*.[A-Za-z]*)\n/g;
print Dumper @data;
```

will give

```
$VAR = [
           John van,
           john@abc.com
       ]
```

if you want to do it line based, my approach would be: (not tested - sharpshoot) :)

```
 my @data = (
                'Name                :john van',
                '',
                'Email Address       :john@abc.com',
                ''
            );
 my (@persons, $name, $email);
 my $gotName = 0;
 my $gotEmail = 0;
 while(@data) { # data is your read in filehandle
     if (/^Name/) {
         $name = $_;
         $name =~ s/.*://;
         chomp($name);
         $gotName++;
     }
     if (/^Email/) {
         $mail= $_;
         $mail=~ s/.*://;
         chomp($mail);
         $gotEmail++;
     }
     if ($gotName == 1 and $gotEmail == 1) {
         push(@persons, ($name,$email));
         $gotName = 0;
         $gotEmail = 0;
     }
}
```

> Is there a better way to parse the files to get the email address and
>   name?

a better way as which one?

> How do I deal with the strings and re arrange them.

what is the question?